# powershell script for connecting HyperV VMM and create a VM from specific template

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

does anyone know is there a way we can connect HyperV-VMM and create a VM using particular template using powershell ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. But SO is not a code writing service, own effort is required to get help. Feel free to edit your question with your work so far and a clear and detailed explanation.

Comment: I am looking for a possibility only. Not a written CODE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The best way to get started with this is to create the template in VMM and go through the creation process for the vm. Before you finish creating it though, on the last page in the bottom corner, you will see a view script button. This actually gives you the powershell version of what is being performed from the GUI.